# Multiple criterion Sumifs formula in vba for

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert the difference between excel sumifs formulas to a code in vba such that it caclulates the values directly, i.e. without actual R1C1 formula calculation.
I have about 5000 rows for such calculation and that's why calculating R1C1 formula with subsequent converting it to values takes too long.

This is how my formula looks in Excel:

```
=SUMIFS($I:$I;$G:$G;"="&Product;$A:$A;"="&$A9;$C:$C;"="&$C9;$F:$F;"="&$F9;$B:$B;"="&$B9)-SUMIFS($I:$I;$G:$G;"="&Line;$A:$A;"="&$A9;$C:$C;"="&$C9;$F:$F;"="&$F9;$B:$B;"="&$B9)
```

Where Product adn Line are the defined names.

And this is how I tried to convert it to vba but it does not work as it should:

```
Sub Test()
With Worksheets("Table")
    With .Range("A6", .Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 7)
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("I:I"), Range("G:G"), Range("Product"), Range("A:A"), Range("A9").Value, Range("C:C"), Range("C9").Value, Range("f:f"), Range("F9").Value, Range("B:B"), Range("B9").Value) - Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("I:I"), Range("G:G"), Range("Line"), Range("A:A"), Range("A9").Value, Range("C:C"), Range("C9").Value, Range("f:f"), Range("f9").Value, Range("b:b"), Range("b9").Value)

    End With
End With

End Sub
```

It does not work as it should because the formula does not move with the cell ranges, i.e. the first cell refers to row 9 and the macro should run like that so that it drags it down to the row 10, 11, 12, etc. In the current setup it stays on row 9 and calculates for row 9 on each rows.count

What should I change ?

Is there anybody who could help??

Comment: With this kind of formula I would use the macro record to get the exact formula for VBA and then replace with variables if needed.

Comment: yeah but then as I mentioned I would need to use formula R1C1 and subseqently convert to values. This is not possible because the macro would take too long time for me as I have about 5000 lines and may have even more. That's why I need vba-based sumifs which would avoid this timely calculations

Comment: But doing what I said will give you the formula which you will convert into the `application.sumifs()`both share the same arguments and order. You just need to clean a bit the code. Thought I think you can't use multiple criterias from different sheets... All the criterias must be taken from the same sheet you are going to sum.

Comment: I've checked your code
1. Delete `.` before Range and Cells in first row AND 
2. `""="" & Range("Product") - > change to Range("Product")

Comment: I have changed the part with ""="". But I am not sure to which dot before Range and Cells you are referring to? I have only dots before Range when I am specifying the sheet which is needed.

Comment: @Damian: That's what I have already done. I always first record and then try to write it. I am stacked so I am asking for a help.

Comment: *calculation result is wrong*... how wrong is it? Zero result, `#NA`, `#VALUE`? Without data, it is hard to tell. You may be missing a higher level `With` block. And seeing your clean up edit, this might be due to sheet referencing. Are you running VBA on the *Table* sheet or `ThisWorkbook` module or a standalone module? Your edit does not period qualify the `.Range` calls. Without context, it is hard to help.

Comment: I am running on the table sheet only. The higher WIth block level is just With Worksheets("Table")

Comment: I have added the 2nd edit, to clear it out.